# go-ethereum: deploy contract with pub + private + key + password

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, authentication

I'm not sure if I create the right title.
But the problem is: I do have a public and private key from ganache network.

I want to deploy contract using go-ethereum which requires me to setup keystore file https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/bind/auth.go#L33

Seems like an easy question - how to run unlock address without keystore file, just with private key and password but I cannot find solution yet (

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to start the geth

geth --datadir ./datadir --networkid 2018 --port 30303 --rpc --rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug” --rpccorsdomain=”*” --rpcaddr=[your ip] --rpcport 8545 --unlock 0 console

Enter your passphrase which will unlock the account and then you can deploy the smart contract. Hope it helps.